# Why the canonical epimorphism $\pi:F\rightarrow F/IF$ is a one to one map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

The statement is the following:

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity, $I(\neq R)$ an ideal of $R$,$F$ a free $R$-module with basis $X$ and $\pi:F\rightarrow F/IF$ the canonical epimorphism. Then $F/IF$ is a free $R/I$-module with basis $\pi(X)$ and $|\pi(X)|=|X|$.(The action of $F/IF$ over $R/I$ is given by $(r+I)(a+IF)=ra+IF$)

The sketch of proof is the following:

1. Prove that $\pi(x_1),\cdots,\pi(x_n)$ can span the image.
2. Prove that $\pi(x_1),\cdots,\pi(x_n)$ is linear independent.
3. Prove that the canonical epimorphism is one to one to conclude $|\pi(X)|=|X|$.

There is two things that I do not understand:

- Since both the basis $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and the basis $\pi(x_1),\cdots,\pi(x_n)$ is linear independent. Why can't conclude $|\pi(X)|=|X|$ directly?
- I can not understand the one to one intuitionally(although I understand the proof) because I think the number of element of $F/IF$ and the $R/I$ is obviously smaller than that of $F$ and $R$.

Thanks for the answer! Since the theorem is found in **Algebra** by Hungerford, maybe I midunderstand the proof in the book when writing the above sketch of proof:
[image]
If there is something wrong with my understanding, could you point out?

Comment: It’s one-to-one because different basis elements of $F$ go to different basis elements of $F/IF$. Needless to say, the map $F\to F/IF$ is not one-to-one (unless $I=(0)$ ). That is, your title gets the facts wrong.

Comment: Got it! Thank you:)@Lubin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, showing that $\pi(x_1),\ldots, \pi(x_n)$ are linearly independent suffices to show that $\lvert X\rvert=\lvert \pi(X)\rvert$. On the other hand, note that this quotient map is in general not injective unless you are quotienting by the zero ideal. For instance, $\Bbb{Z}$ is a free rank $1$ module over itself with basis $1$. Quotient by $(2)$ to get $\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}/2\to 0$. This is clearly not injective (indeed, all even numbers are sent to $0\in \Bbb{Z}/2$).